# How to send data to an api having multiple Nested Arrays in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I have to send the modified data to an api which has json format as below:

```
{
"Customer": {
    "name": "ABC",
    "email": ABC@gmail.com,
    "password": ""
},
"access": true,
"time": 2000
}
```

On save I want to set the respective state to api fields.

```
save=()=>{
    let newCustomer={
        access:this.state.access,
        time:this.state.time,
        name:      //How can i set the state values for name,email and 
                     password which is in nested form?
        email:
        password:

    }
     return axios.put('api',newCustomer)
     .then(response => {

    })
}
```

Comment: What’s the issue are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly declare it like your json format.

```
let newCustomer={
  access:this.state.access,
  time:this.state.time,
  Customer: {
    name: ..., // state name from your nested form
    email: ...,  // state email from your nested form
    password: ..., // state password from your nested form
  },
}
```

Comment: You might could mark this as answer to help others to fix the same problem. :D @Pooja

Comment: I have marked it as useful.Since my reputation is not more than 15 it won't be displayed publicly but the votes will be considered @Bukhari

Answer (score 0):

```
        save=(Customer)=>{
            let newCustomer={
                ...Customer,
                access: this.state.access,
                time: this.state.time,
            }
            return axios.put('api', newCustomer)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
        }
```

Then `newCustomer` will be like `Customer` but access and time may be different.
In backend you cann access customer name and email like you are accessing an array